# Syntax Error with Python MySQL Connector

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm struggling with a simple query within Python.

The query is (concentrated in one line in Python):

```
SELECT SUM(valor) FROM base WHERE deb="Itau" and MONTH(data)=11 and YEAR(data)=2017
```

I get a SyntaxError on the line

```
query = ("SELECT SUM(valor) FROM base WHERE cred="Itau" and MONTH(data)=11 and YEAR(data)=2017")
```

Afterwards I run the query with `cursor.execute(query)`.

What I don't understand is that the query works fine when using Sequel Pro or directly in MariaDB shell.

Any idea what that may be?

Please feel free to criticize the method. The aim is to retrieve information from MariaDB using Python and then feed it to a table (DataTable) and a chart (Chart.JS or Moris.JS) on an HTML web app.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The syntax highlighting doesn't give it away?

Comment: Not that I can identify, I get (the  ^ is right bellow Itau)

File "testebase.py", line 20
    query_saidas = ("SELECT SUM(valor) FROM base WHERE cred="Itau" and MONTH(data)=11 and YEAR(data)=2017")
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotation is what's causing the problem. Use single quotations within double quotations like so

```
query = ("SELECT SUM(valor) FROM base WHERE cred='Itau' and MONTH(data)=11 and YEAR(data)=2017")
```

Comment: With single quotations I get the following traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testebase.py", line 24, in <module>
    entradas = cursor.execute(query_entradas)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 521, in execute
    self._connection.handle_unread_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1059, in handle_unread_result
    raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

Comment: don't know exactly what was causing the problem, but I rewrote the connection cursor and changed to single quotation and it worked, thanks a lot!